# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception debug.keystore

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problems running the app as below error code

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Acer\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The keystore file located at *C:\Users\Acer.android* seems to be causing this issue. Maybe it is corrupt.

Try going to `Build -> Clean Project` and then rebuild the project or run the app.

If this does not work, try going to `File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and restart.`

If this does not work, delete the keystore file in C:\Users\Acer.android and run the project.

If this does not work, delete the '.android' folder and build the project again.